90's movie with a girl who goes crazy and grows vine tattoos on her body
My husband tried to explain this movie to me... so humor me. He said he caught the last 30 minutes of this movie and he believes that Jason or Jeremy London was in it.  I tried checking IMDb, but got frustrated.
He believes they were high schoolers. One of the London brothers was on a tape having sex with a girl and it was played at a party.  The girl flipped out and got angry, she started growing vine tattoos on her body and killing people and starting fires. He said the movie was probably 90's and in English. That's all I've got.

You're describing a scene from The Rage: Carrie 2 from 1999 with Jason London.

A massacre strikes up after an outcast girl is taunted by a group of high school jocks, all of them unaware of her violent, cutthroat psychic power. 

You can see the relevant scene here (Warning: Graphic), and here's the trailer:




That looks like what he descibed.  So excited, I had no idea there was a sequel to Carrie...cannot wait to netflix it.  Thanks for your help. Walt 4 president
